# Google Blogger Comments Stuck On Opening

Tags: html, google-plus

I recently found a way to add google comments into my site.  However, whenever I try to enter a comment, it just gets stuck on Opening... forever.  On other computers it works fine.

My current code is below:

```
<div class="g-comments"
    data-href="http://www.thecodingeagle.com/"
    data-width="642"
    data-first_party_property="BLOGGER"
    data-view_type="FILTERED_POSTMOD"></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In Google Chrome, Firefox or InternetExplorer? Tried clear cache?

Comment: Google Chrome, latest version.  Tried clearing the cache, but it didn't work.